# Python: How do I get a part of a string which is in between two known parts of string?

Tags: python-3.x

Heres my code:

```
import requests
import json

import requests

url =("http://yugiohprices.com/api/get_card_prices/Armed Dragon LV5")

resp = requests.get(url=url)
data = resp.json() # Check the JSON Response Content documentation below
json_string = json.dumps(data)
print(json_string)
print("---------------------")
```

Running this gives me:

```
{"status": "success", "data": [{"name": "Legendary Duelists: Ancient Millennium", "print_tag": "LED2-EN026", "rarity": "Common", "price_data":
```

and i want to get specifically just the "Legendary Duelists: Ancient Millennium" bit.

using

```
json_string.split("name")[1]
```

takes it down to

```
": "Legendary Duelists: Ancient Millennium", "print_tag": "LED2-EN026", "rarity": "Common", "price_data": {
```

but how do I get rid of the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resp = requests.get(url=url)
data = resp.json() # Check the JSON Response Content documentation below
json_string = json.dumps(data)
```

What this code does: getting a response from `url`, converting to a dictionary and then converting it back to a string.

You already have a dictionary which is far easier to work with than a string. Also, There is no guarantee that the server will always return the response in the same order (which will obviously break any attempt to parse the response as a string).

Access the data you need with keys:

```
import requests
import json

url = ("http://yugiohprices.com/api/get_card_prices/Armed Dragon LV5")

resp = requests.get(url=url)
response_json = resp.json()

print(response_json['data'][0]['name'])
# Legendary Duelists: Ancient Millennium
```

If you want to get all the names, use a loop:

```
for data in response_json['data']:
    print(data['name'])
```

will output

```
Legendary Duelists: Ancient Millennium
Structure Deck: Dragon's Roar
Duelist Pack: Chazz Princeton
Legendary Collection 3: Yugi's World Mega Pack
Dark Revelation Volume 3
Soul of the Duelist
Dragunity Legion Structure Deck
Soul of the Duelist
```

Comment: This solved my question, thank you! I'll mark it as solved when it lets me.